# How can i send custom data along with push notification?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

i have one use case in which I need to send custom data along with push notification in Google Assistant using ActionOnSDK , how can I send it anyone has any clue?

```js
let notification = {
        userNotification: {
            title: 'A new tip is added',
        },
        target: {
            userId: 'abcd1234-EFGH_789',
            intent: 'tell_latest_tip',
            // Expects a IETF BCP-47 language code (i.e. en-US)
            locale: 'en-US'
        },
    };

request.post('https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send', {
    'auth': {
        'bearer': tokens.access_token,
    },
    'json': true,
    'body': {
        'customPushMessage': notification
    }
};
```

Comment: What custom data do you need to send and why? How do you see this custom data to be used?

Comment: @Prisoner, i want to send list in JSON format, when user gets push notifation and top on that push notification then i want that json list in event at actionOnGoogle request

Comment: So you want some information available when the Intent is triggered in the Action?